# Capturing Lightning Performance (Page Load Time) without any special tools?

Tags: lightning, developer-console, performance, workbench, eventlogfile

I have been requested to come up with a report or analysis that could "show performance of the page load for a certain period of time or something similar"

**Business problem:** 
Some customers currently complain the Lightening pages take longer compared to Classic pages.

My higher up will not give me access to the WorkBench so I am unable to use APIs and we do not use the WAVE or Analytics Apps.

I have gone through the Event Monitoring Trailhead, but I am having a hard time trying to figure out how to search for page load time through the Developer Console.

Does anyone have Salesforce Documentation they can provide or other information that can help me?

Comment: Meanwhile can you see whats your octane score? you can check that by doing speedtest.  `https://yoursfinstanceurl.com/speedtest.jsp`

Comment: My octane score is 17,167

Comment: You might be using slow machine. SF says anything 20K octane score, Lightning Experinec will struggle. `, Lightning Experience performance will likely be slow (20,000 at minimum if using Salesforce Console). A high-end client device typically has an Octane score greater than 32,000. The higher the Octane score, the better Lightning Experience performance will be.`
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000250291&language=en_US&type=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Lightning Inspector contains a tab which called Performance. In there, you can measure the actual page load performance like this:
[image: performance tab in lightning inpsector]

With this way, you can teach your customers how they can create report like this and then you can measure what and how is going on in their browsers.

Link to the extension:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/salesforce-lightning-insp/pcpmcffcomlcjgpcheokdfcjipanjdpc