# Capturing page performance statistics with Event Monitoring?

Tags: lightning, api, performance, workbench, eventlogfile

I've finished the trailhead for event monitoring. In the trail head it mentions

"Optimize performance — Sometimes it’s hard to determine the cause of slow page performance in your organization. Imagine that your company has an office in San Francisco and one in London. The users in London tell you that their reports are running slowly or even timing out. You can use event monitoring to determine whether the cause is related to a network issue in London or with the way your app is configured."

I've been using workbench/Rest API, and have not figured out a way to use EventLogFile to do this sort of thing for Lightning and Classic pages and most documentation I've read doesn't cover this.

Is it possible?

This answer is different then the previous question because I am able to use workbench, or the APIs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capturing Lightning Performance (Page Load Time) without any special tools?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/255704/capturing-lightning-performance-page-load-time-without-any-special-tools)

Comment: I asked that question yesterday, and tried deleting it, but now I can use the tools where as in the other post my boss wouldn't allow me to.

Answer (score 0):

You can view event logs files for any sandbox/production org using [this](https://salesforce-elf.herokuapp.com/) heroku app.

There is more information on viewing the logs in [this](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/event_monitoring/event_monitoring_download) salesforce trailhead